# How to create callback function when upload failed by XUpload Extension on Yii?

Tags: yii, upload, event-handling, yii-extensions, yii-xupload

I'm using XUpload Extension to multiupload onto my site base yii framework. It's work very well. Until I try rename upload folder, xupload upload failed! I can predict this case. But I don't know how to create callbacks when the upload is successful or when it fails to show notification on my site:

This is [Oficial Xupload Extension page](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/)

This is my code:

```
$this->widget(
    $className  = 'ext.xupload.XUploadWidget',
    $properties = array(
        'url' => "http://localhost/Upload/multiupload.php"),

        ...//another config here

        'options' => array(
            'beforeSend' => 'js:function(event, files, index, xhr, handler, callBack) {
                handler.uploadRow.find(".upload_start button").click(callBack);
            }',

            //Callback function when upload complete
            'onComplete'=>'js:function(event, files, index, xhr, handler, callBack) {
                if(xhr.status==200) {
                    alert("Ok");
                } else {
                    alert("Error"+ xhr.status);
                }
            }',
        ),
    )
);
```

You can see `onComplete` event running when upload successful, but it doesn't when upload fails. How to handle upload failure event?

Comment: I was found the answer! I must use `onError` instead of `onComplete`, and `xupload` widget can handle upload failure event!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

There is something like 'fail' in the jquery.fileupload.js file.

```
        // Callback for failed (abort or error) uploads:
        // fail: function (e, data) {}, // .bind('fileuploadfail', func);
```